# When I die and leave a clone behind, is my bound weapon now bound to the clone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, resurrection

So I have an eldritch knight who was rewarded by a powerful wizard with a clone. A few months later and he ends up dying by being thrown off a cliff. Now that he's back he has 0 gear because of the spell, but he had bonded with a pretty nice Magical warhammer that exploded when he hit stuff. and is wanting to summon it to his hand. Is he still bound to it or does he have to start all over?

I am playing 5e.

Comment: When you say now he's back do you mean now you are playing as his clone?

Comment: related: [ways to break a weapon bond](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108941/can-an-eldritch-knight-s-weapon-bond-be-broken)

Answer (score 7):

the clone spell description says as following

> At any time after the clone matures, if the original creature dies, **its soul transfers to the clone**, provided that the soul is free and willing to return. The clone is physically identical to the original and has the same personality, memories, and abilities, **but none of the original’s equipment**. The original creature’s physical remains, if they still exist, become inert and can’t thereafter be restored to life, since the creature’s soul is elsewhere.

So here it says 2 things, first it says the soul is transferred to the clone, then it says the clone has none of the equipment. So okay, you don't keep the hammer, but that should be interpreted as a result of the items not magically being transported to your clone. The clone does contain all your memories and abilities, but the `weapon bond` ability doesn't explain that the bonding happens between your weapon and your soul, so that's something the DM would have to grant you. If the DM grants that the hammer is bonded to your soul then I would say you have a good case to argue that you should be able to summon the hammer.

It seems to me the DM has to make some decisions here as the descriptions are a bit soft..

Answer (score 3):

The bond is not broken when you die. Therefore, any kind of ressurection keeps the bond intact.

You still keep all class features, and the text on the weapon bond does not state it is broken by death.

The hammer is still not on your character, but you should be able to summon it when you get to use a bonus action, if the bond is not broken by other means, or the hammer is barred from teleportation (in a antimagic field, for example).